# Async load data in BaseController, how to make controller constructor async

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-6.0

I run .net core 6 version, and I have no idea how to make constructor of my controller (BaseController) async, because i am calling async service to load items in Menu. Menu is on every page, so any other of my controllers (AccountController, OrderController) inherits from my BaseController.

It must be loaded in constructor, just on creating the controller, I cant hang on it on another action. Right now, when i just make it sync, on first page call there are no preloaded data, because it's not waiting on completition.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    private readonly ICategoryService _categoryService;
    protected readonly IMapper _mapper;
    protected LayoutViewModel _layoutViewModel = new LayoutViewModel();

    public BaseController(ICategoryService categoryService, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _categoryService = categoryService;
        _mapper = mapper;
        LoadRankedCategories();
    }

    public void LoadCategories()
    {
        var categories = _categoryService.GetCategoriesAsync();
        _layoutViewModel.Categories = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<MenuCategoryViewModel>>(categories);
    }
}
```

Comment: Controllers cant be Async. You could look into using Lazy to populate what you need one time when requested, and have data be initialized from that point on. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=net-6.0

Comment: I will better use cache over Lazy for storing categories, but it's not answering me how to solve the problem with calling async task/service from controller constructor.

Comment: The answer is "Dont" Constructors should not have async code in them, its generally bad practice. You could force async code to execute syncronously in a constructor but thats an issue to google at your own risk.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, on controller construction start the asynchronous task and save said task in a field.  Then make sure you await said task whenever you need the results.

```cs
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    private Task _categoriesTask;

    public BaseController()
    {
        _categoriesTask = LoadCategoriesAsync();
    }

    private async Task LoadCategoriesAsync()
    {
        var rawCategories = await _categoryService.GetCategoriesAsync();
        return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<MenuCategoryViewModel>>(rawCategories);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SomeGet()
    {
        // Await the class-level task.
        var categories = await _categoriesTask;
        ...
    }
}
```

**NOTE**:  As I see the sample here, however, you should do this in the *static* constructor or use some caching mechanism like memcached (if microservices or distributed) or Redis, assuming the categories never change.  So take the solution as a purely academic response on how to overcome the problem.  In reality, this doesn't feel right for the stated reason.

Finally, I wouldn't recommend this at all unless there is absolutely no other way:  You can spawn a new thread and block it with `Result`.  This might carry undesired issues, so use it at your own risk.

```cs
    public BaseController()
    {
        // This will get you the actual categories.
        _categories = Task.Run(() => LoadCategoriesAsync()).Result();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to run LoadCategories in constructor, or on load. You are hanging it on Get action.

Comment: Ok, edited to give you one more option.

Comment: This approach I already tried, and i am not sure it's correct. It can probably cause some deadlocks. By default, controller construct doesnt support async calling by design. So it's maybe best approach to just create Sync method which I call, instead of async. Because async method doesn't do any better, there is no support. Controller support only async on IActionResult.

I was just curious if there is no any other approach.